# Using .createServer to make a public website

Tags: node.js, json, hosting

So I have a file I want to host from my computer, and I want to be able to listen at the port for various reasons. I'm using

```js
const port = [number]
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let responseCode = 404;
    let content = '404 Error';

    const urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true);

    if (urlObj.query.code) {
        const accessCode = urlObj.query.code;
    }

    if (urlObj.pathname === '/') {
        responseCode = 200;
        content = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(responseCode, {
        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
    });

    res.write(content);
    res.end();
})
    .listen(port);
```

and all that good stuff makes it where I can have a local file, `http://localhost:[number]`. However, I'm not exactly sure how I can use this same method for hosting on an online website, one in which I upload my code to the website then have the website started from my computer (using the create server). Does anyone know how to basically create a server that's not private/local, but instead is public (and yes I can use a web host).

Comment: What ?! Is this a coding question or "how to" you "publish" the server to the interweebz ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [express](https://expressjs.com/) framework as it greatly simplifies serving static files. It would be as simple as the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at port ${port}`);
});
```

With above code all that's left to do is to create folder called `public` in your app directory where you place your `html/css/js` files.